# Getting Signal Strength RSCP and Ec/Io from a phone served by a HSPA network

Tags: android, signals, gsm, signal-strength

I am trying to capture Signal Strength and Ec/Io from my Android app on a phone that's on at&t network. When a phone is being served on WCDMA / HSDPA network, the pertinent RF measurements are RSCP and Ec/Io. How do I obtain the current RSCP and Ec/Io? The GSM Signal Strength and GSM Bit Error Rate are not applicable when the phone is camping on 3G (UMTS/HSDPA/HSPA/HSUPA) network.

Thanks.
Dillon

Answer (score 2):

The signal strength indicator uses the following:

```
[android.telephony.PhoneStateListener][1]
```

If you're using an i9000 based modem, you can dial the following:

***#0011#**

This will give you the WCDMA band you're on, DL and UL frequencies, Cell ID and LAC, and RSCP / ECIO values.